# How can I search for a file using tcl, with only part of the file name

Tags: regex, bash, foreach, tcl, ls

If I have a folder with the following files:

```
hello-version-1-090.txt
hello-awesome-well-091.txt
goodday-087.txt
hellooo-874.txt
hello_476.txt
hello_094.txt
```

How can I search for a file which has the term: 'hello' and '091' in it using tcl.

Possible solution:
taking the output of an `ls -l` in a folder, splitting it with `'\n'` and then running a `foreach` on each line and using regexp to match the criteria. But how do I run an `ls -l` in a folder and record its save its contents (the file names) using tcl?

Comment: You can even have the `glob` command recursively scan a directory and all sub-directories which could be useful to you as well. I would take a look at the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `glob`, you can apply the pattern and can get the list of file names matching our criteria.

```
puts [ exec ls -l ]; #Just printing the 'ls -l' output
set myfiles [ glob -nocomplain hello*091*.txt ]
if {[llength $myfiles]!=0} {
    puts "Following files matched your pattern : "
    foreach fname $myfiles {
        puts $fname
    }
} else {
    puts "No files matched your pattern"
}
```

The reason for using `-nocomplain` is to allow an empty list to be returned without error if there is no file matched with our search pattern.

**Output**

```
sh-4.2# tclsh main.tcl                                                                                                         
total 4                                                                                                                        
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Mar  4 15:23 goodday-087.txt                                                                        
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Mar  4 15:23 hello-awesome-well-091.txt                                                             
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Mar  4 15:23 hello-version-1-090.txt                                                                
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Mar  4 15:23 hello_094.txt                                                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Mar  4 15:23 hello_476.txt                                                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Mar  4 15:23 hellooo-874.txt                                                                        
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 262 Mar  4 15:24 main.tcl                                                                               
Following files matched your pattern :                                                                                         
hello-awesome-well-091.txt
```

By the way, with respect to your query on how to save the `ls -l` output, simply save the output to a variable.

```
set result [ exec ls -l ]
```

Then with the `result` variable, you can apply `regexp` by means of looping line by line just as you have mentioned.

But, I hope that using `glob` would be a better approach.

Reference : [glob](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm)

Comment: The Glob method is way more elegant, Thanks a lot!!